# My Nvidia drivers are not used for OpenGL rendering?

Tags: linux, opengl, redhat, nvidia, glx

I am trying to execute a c++ code which is using OpenGL(4.x is needed) on Red-hat linux OS. it is throwing the below error.

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
```

Hardware info: 
OS: Linux POWER LE RHEL 7

Accessing the screen through VNC Viewer.

below are the lspci outputs:

```
 lspci | grep VGA
0002:02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)

lspci | grep 3D
0004:04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GV100GL [Tesla V100 SXM2] (rev a1)
0035:03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GV100GL [Tesla V100 SXM2] (rev a1)
```

I thought my machine opengl's version is not matching with required version of the program. so I checked the glxinfo and  below is the output

```
glxinfo
name of display: :3
display: :3  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, GLX_EXT_swap_control, 
    GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_NV_copy_buffer, 
    GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer, 
    GLX_NV_multisample_coverage, GLX_NV_present_video, 
    GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_NV_swap_group, 
    GLX_NV_video_capture, GLX_NV_video_out, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 17.2.3)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_vertex_array, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_lod
```

Here it is showing the version 1.4. and the OpenGL vendor string is not Nvidia. and direct rendering is NO. seems it is using cpu for rendering.

How can I make my nvidia drivers to be used for gl rendering? 
And if nvidia drivers are used then my OpenGL version will increase?

Comment: Did you ever solve this by chance?